# Actions Class in Selenium not suggesting methods available

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, tooltip, content-assist

I'm trying to use Actions class of Selenium but I don't why in my IDE it doesn't work when I'm calling a method from this class.

I've imported the following:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action;
```

instantiated the Actions class:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
```

Tried to call a method from Actions class, but there are no suggestions.

```
action.
```

[image: call methods from Actions class]

Hope you could help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The import for [Actions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) *Class* is:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
```

Now, while working with *Selenium Java* clients within *Eclipse* environment to activate the suggestions you need to *activate* the **Content Assist** for **Auto Activation** as per the snapshot below you need to traverse through: `Window` -> `Preference` -> `Editor` -> `Content Assist` and set the *Auto Activation* options as per the snapshot below:

[image: ContentAssist]